# Can I extend a partition that is already used as a LVM PV?

Tags: partition, lvm

Not really familiar with LVM and partitionning, usually, I :

- extend a virtual disk (where there is already a PV on it)
- create a new partition with the new free space
- create a new PV from it
- add it to my volum group

My question is, can I, instead :

- extend a virtual disk (where there is already a PV on it)
- delete the existing partition and recreate it adding the new free space
- extend the existing PV
- extend the VG

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by a virtual disk, but if you have a way of increasing the block device with a PV on it, you can use the `pvresize` command to grow the PV to the new size of the block device. Once the PV has grown, you will need to use `lvextend` to give more space to your selected LV; and finally, use `resize2fs` (assuming ext2/3/4) to grow the filesystem to use the new LV space.

Comment: I mean a VMware disk for example.